# JSF and Richfaces rich:select and f:selectItems

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

how to highlight elements in a list with different colors using JSF and Richfaces

Answer (score 1):

You may try using the jQuery odd and even selectors on table row selectors shown in the [rich faces docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Tables_and_grids.html#sect-Component_Reference-richdataTable-Style_classes_and_skin_parameters) i.e. `.rf-dt-r` and apply a different class.

something like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

  //for table row
  $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
  $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#EFF1F1");
});
</script>
```

As seen in [this](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/different-color-alternate-row-jquery.html) page.